# Borrar Tools for Native Modules de Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, delete

estaba instalando nodejs y por error acepte la opción de instalar "Tool for Native Modules", la pregunta es en donde puedo encontrar esas carpetas para eliminarlas y si existe algún problema con borrarlas, Gracias :D
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que 7na mejor opción sería desinstalar y volverlo a instalar

Comment: Si, fue la mejor opción, al final opte por hacer eso, gracias :D

Comment: jaja, un poco tarde el comentario pero buen :D